# Tic-Tac-Toe game isn't switching players, updating score or changing players

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a 2-player Tic-Tac-Toe project and I've ran into an issue where my program isn't changing the player and isn't switching the player correctly. In addition, my program is also having issues updating the score, which I'm using to determine a win condition by using binary logic, bit-wise operators, and the array to determine when a win condition is reached.

```js
var player1name = "";
var player2name = "";
var firstPlayer = player1name;
var player1 = 0; //score for all games
var player2 = 0; //score for all games
var scoreX = 0; //player "X" score on current board
var scoreO = 0; //player "X" score on current board
var value = 0; //button binary value
var player = "X"; //current player's turn X or O
var winner = ""; //stores winner X or O
var winArray = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];
var clickedArray = [];
var clicksCount = 0;
var currentPlayer = ""; //get player's name

function start() {
  //alert("start");
  player1name = prompt("Enter first player's name:", "");
  player2name = prompt("Enter second player's name:", "");
  currentPlayer = player1name;
  document.getElementById("player").innerHTML =
currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
}

function playerMoved(id, value) {
  changeText(id);
  updateScore(value);

  //check for winner
  if (player === "X") {
check4winner(scoreX);
  } else {
check4winner(scoreO);
  }

  //was there a winner?
  if (winner !== "") {
//alert("winner:" + winner);
//logic to display winner
document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = currentPlayer + " won!";
startNewGame();
  } else {
changePlayer();
  }
  switchPlayer();
}

function changeText(id) {
  //alert("changeText: " + player);
  //alert(id.innerHTML);
  if (id.innerHTML === "") {
//storing id's of clicked div to reset later
clickedArray[clicksCount] = id;
clicksCount = clicksCount + 1;

if (player === "X") {
  id.innerHTML = "X";
} else {
  id.innerHTML = "O";
}
  }
}

function switchPlayer() {
  //alert("switchPlayer");
  //switch player prompt
  if (currentPlayer === player1name) {
currentPlayer = player2name;
  } else {
currentPlayer = player1name;
  }
  //re-display current player in h2
  document.getElementById("player").innerHTML =
currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
}

function updateScore(value) {
  //alert("updateScore");
  //alert("Update Score for " + player);
  if (player === "X") {
scoreX = scorex + value;
alert("scoreX: " + scoreX);
  } else {
scoreO = scoreO + value;
alert("scoreO: " + scoreO);
  }
  alert("PlayerX Score: " + scoreX + " PlayerO Score: " + scoreO);
}

function check4winner(score) {
  //alert("Checking for winner" + score);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < winsArray.length; i++) {
if ((winsArray[i] & score) === winsArray[i]) {
  if (player === "X") {
    winner = "X";
  } else {
    winner = "O";
  }
  alert(winner + "Won!");
  i = 99; //break out of for loop
}
  }
}

function changePlayer() {
  //alert("Changed Player: " + player);
  if (player === "X") {
player = "O";
  } else {
player = "X";
  }
  document.getElementById("player").innerHTML =
currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
}

function startNewGame() {
  //alert("Start new game");
  winner = "";
  scoreO = 0;
  scoreX = 0;
  //reset all clicked squares
  for (i = 0; i < clickedArray.length; i++) {
clickedArray[i].innerHTML = "";
  }
  //change who goes first
  if (firstPlayer === player1name) {
firstPlayer = player2name;
  } else {
firstPlayer = player1name;
  }
  currentPlayer = firstPlayer;
  document.getElementById("player").innerHTML =
currentPlayer + " choose a square.";
  //update scores
}
```

```css
.Table {
  display: table;
}

.Row {
  display: table-row;
}
            
.Cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: dashed black 2px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #3B653D;
  color: #FFFEFA;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="start()">
  <div className="Table">
<div className="Title">
  <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
  <h2 id="winner" />
  <h2 id="player" />
  <div className="Row">
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 1)" />
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 2)" />
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 4)" />
  </div>
  <div className="Row">
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 8)" />
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 16)" />
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 32)" />
  </div>
  <div className="Row">
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 64)" />
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 128)" />
    <div class="Cell" onclick="playerMoved(this, 256)" />
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>;
```

Comment: Can you please narrow down where your problem is and just post a few lines of code that exhibit the specific issue?

Comment: I would, but I'm new to programming and I'm not exactly sure where my issue is. Sorry!

Comment: @BenK If you were able to write what you posted here, I'm sure you're also able to write `console.log(variable_name);` throughout the code to track down a few bugs. You must have *some* idea or expectation of how it's supposed to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about the error console in your browser's [Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). When making a move, it provides the following error:

> js:137 Uncaught ReferenceError: scorex is not defined

These clues help you figure out when there are problems in your code. For example, in this error, it shows that on line 137, you are using a variable called `scorex` (note the lowercase X). Your real variable includes a capital X, though. Once JavaScript encounters the error, it stops executing.

JavaScript is throwing the error because `scorex` is not a defined variable. Change it to `scoreX` and it will get past that error. Variables are case-sensitive.

There are more errors after this, though, so I will let you figure those out. I'll give you a hint: `winArray` or `winsArray`?

Comment: `scorex` is undefined but once that is fixed, `winsArray` is also undefined. Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv1uhkhu/

Comment: Thanks, for bringing the Dev Tools to my attention. I'm new to programming and haven't heard of a lot of the tools out there.

Comment: @Eli "Working" is not the exact word, because it does not tell you when you win in [this case, for example](http://i.imgur.com/1JR7msF.png).

Comment: @blex it fixes the problem he was having, doesn't it?

Comment: @BenK It is really an invaluable tool in debugging code problems in JavaScript. There are dev tools built into every browser that help you understand how the browser handles your code (JS, CSS, HTML). Good luck with your game. Its a great place to start so you can encounter these types of problems and learn how to resolve them.